# execute command in subdirectories

Tags: unix, redirect, for-loop, output

I want to run a program for a file that exists in different subdirectories and then redirect the output to an output file. I want the output to be saved to the directory that the program has run.

So I would like to do something like this:

```
for x in */*.txt; do command $x > output.fsa; done
```

My questions are:

1. Is it correct the above loop? should I change directory  in order to save the output on the directory that the command was executed or linux takes care of it?
2. any ideas on how to give the name of the directory in the output file?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct the above loop?

Yes

> should I change directory in order to save the output on the directory that the command was executed or linux takes care of it?

You do not need to change the directory it is enough to redirect the output to a file in the correct directory:

```
for x in */*.txt; do command $x > `dirname $x`/output.fsa; done
```

Comment: I think you meant `dirname`, not `basename`.

Comment: nice I can see that the dirname will give me different names to the output file.

Comment: Unless you call command `cd` your current working directory will NOT change. So in every place in the loop you have still the same cwd (pwd). So yes, you need to specify the dirname for output. You are redirecting it to the relative path, not absolute, read more about it :)

Answer (score 1):

The loop is correct, you will iterate over all txt files in subdirs of the current pwd (where this script or command is being executed). You don't have to change directory to save the output in that subdir. Linux don't take care of it :)

You can delete everything after first `/` using variable expansion `${x%%/*}`

Try

```
for x in */*.txt; do
  command "$x" > "${x%%/*}"/output.fsa
done
```

Remember, if you have more txt files in that subdir, you will execute command "$x" more times and rewrite the output.fsa.

You can use append (`>>`) in that case

Try

```
for x in */*.txt; do
  echo "Executing command \"$x\"" >> "${x%%/*}"/output.fsa
  command "$x" >> "${x%%/*}"/output.fsa
done
```